# spring + springMVC+hibernate create dynamic tables at runtime

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, web

I have a requirement in my web application that can let users enter tables's name, attributes and datatypes to create tables. But as I know, the tables should be defined beforehand in hibernate. Is there any way of doing so?

Thanks in advance,
Tianyi

Comment: Also if anyone can suggest any other method may be without hibernate to achieve it.

Comment: This seems fraught with peril. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: this is not possible.. why do you need to do this ?

Comment: Let users transfer data from paper doc to database. The tables are electronic papers. So there are huge tables that needs to be created.

Comment: You’re storing people’s spreadsheets for them? This is an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/167798).

Comment: Without using tables to store, what else could I do？

Comment: Please look answer of Ken Chan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660396/how-to-create-table-in-database-dynamically-using-hibernate?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)